# div width with jquery in percent

Tags: jquery, width, percentage

I try to adapt this code jquery so that the width of my div "book" is in percentage.

```
<div id="book" class='album'>
d.wowBook.defaults={width:1200,......YES
d.wowBook.defaults={"width:100%",......NO
d.wowBook.defaults={'width:100%',......NO
d.wowBook.defaults={width:"100%",......NO
d.wowBook.defaults={width:100+"%",......NO  

thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide width in percentage by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#book").width('40%');
//or
 $("#book").css('width','40%');
});
```